# What will be the asymptotic time complexity of these two functions?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

See the following two functions.

```
    A(n)
    { if(n<=1)
          return;
      else
          return(A(n/4)+A(n/4)+A(n/4));
    }
```

and the second one-

```
     A(n)
    { if(n<=1)
          return;
      else
          return(3*A(n/4));
    }
```

Please, tell me the equation for both the functions with explanation and then bound it asymptotically.

Actually, why I am asking this question is because, I got an equation

T(n)=3T(n/4)+1

I used Masters and tree method (assuming first case)and got-
   THETA(n^0.79)

But I wish to know why I can't assume this equation to be of 2nd case? One thing, I am sure about is that in both the cases, complexity varies as no. of recursive calls are different in both the case.

Please, help me understand it.

Answer (score 3):

You're absolutely correct in your assertion that the recursion for the first algorithm's time, is

*T(n) = 3 T(n / 4) + O(1)*.

It is also true that the first and second algorithm always return the same thing.

However, this is where the similarity ends. The second algorithm is composed more cleverly, by making a single call, and then multiplying. That is, while

```
return(A(n/4)+A(n/4)+A(n/4));
```

returns the same value as

```
return(3*A(n/4));
```

The latter makes only a single recursive call. Its recursion for the time, therefore is

*T(n) = T(n / 4) + O(1)*

(Here the last *O(1)* includes also the cost of multiplying the return value by 3, which doesn't matter w.r.t. the complexity.)